# Assign two dimensional string array to one dimensional object array

Tags: java, arrays

I get confused with this code

```
String[][] str=new String[2][3];
Object[] obj=str;
```

This compiles fine. because Object is a super class String is a sub class

but the following code produce errors

```
class Ex { } 
class Ex1 extends Ex { } 

class ExTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    Ex1[][] ex1=new Ex1[2][3]; 
    Ex[] ex=ex1; 
  } 
}
```

but this code produce error why

Answer (score 3):

It compiles because `obj` will now hold two one-dimensional `String[]` objects.

All the below will compile:

```
String[][] str = new String[2][3];
Object obj1 = str;
Object[] obj2 = str;
Object[][] obj3 = str;
```

Comment: but String[] str1=str; gives an error because we are assigning two dimensional array of String to one dimensional array ..but Object has exception why ..i still confused

Comment: Because Object is the ultimate super class. String is a subclass of Object.

Comment: class Ex { } class Ex1 extends Ex { } class ExTest { public static void main(String[] args) { Ex1[][] ex1=new Ex1[2][3]; Ex[] ex=ex1; } } but this code produce error why

Answer (score 1):

All array instances are also instance of `java.lang.Object`. Therefore  all below assignments are legal. Elements of `objArr1` array are one dimensional `String` array.

```
     Object obj1 = new String[3];
     Object obj2 = new int[3];
     Object obj3 = new String[3][3];
     Object[] objArr1 = new String[3][4];
```

UPDATE :

```
class Ex { } 
class Ex1 extends Ex { } 
class ExTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Ex1[][] ex1=new Ex1[2][3]; 
    Ex1[][][] exArr=new Ex1[2][3][3]; 
    Object obj = exArr; //valid
    Object objArr[] = ex1; // valid assignment. every array instances are also object
    Object[][] obj2Arr = exArr;  // valid 
    Object[][][] obj3Arr = exArr; //valid
    Obejct[][][][] obj4Arr = exArr; //compiler error. obj4Arr is 4 dimensional, whereas exArr is three..
    Ex[] ex=ex1;  // compiler error
    Ex1[] ex1Arr = ex1 ; // compiler error
  } 
}
```

You can not assign different dimensional array to each other, even if their element types are the same.. You can assign any array with any dimension to an Object array whose dimension is less than or equal to assigned array dimension. Because every array instance is also Object instance..

Comment: yes, but Ex1[] is assignable to Ex[], but not to Ex[][] or Ex.

Comment: i am sorry for asking again and again ..i thought this reflects is a relation ship between super and subclass..this works with Object but no other super class..

Comment: no, it is not relationship between super and subclass. You should accept this fact,"every array no matter how many dimension or whatever element type is Object " as an axiom. I would recommend you to read related part of JLS. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense when you realize that java arrays, no matter how many dimesions they have, are ... Objects in the terms of IS-A relationship. So array of objects can hold pretty much any array since every array is an *Object*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to highlight:

**Object is the direct super class for all the array types**

whether it is single dimension array or multi dimension

or array of String or array of any other derived type.

> I get confused with this code
>
> ```
> String[][] str=new String[2][3];
> Object[] obj=str;
> ```
>
> This compiles fine. because Object is a super class String is a sub
>   class

here suppose we have

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[2];
objArray[0]= // it can hold something which is of type object
            // as we know String[] IS A Object, so I can assign it here like below
String[] strArray = new String[3];
objArray[0] = strArray ;
```

here I am assigning a single dimension `String` array as element of `objArray`, so we can say objArray can hold 2d String array i.e `String[][]` i.e.

```
Object[] objArray = new String[2][];
```

> but the following code produce errors
>
> ```
>  class Ex { } 
> class Ex1 extends Ex { } 
> class ExTest {
>  public static void main(String[] args) 
> { Ex1[][] ex1=new Ex1[2][3]; Ex[] ex=ex1; 
> } }
> ```
>
> but this code produce error why

it is because `ex[0]` can hold something which IS A `Ex`.

suppose if `Ex[] ex=ex1;` is allowed

then `ex[0]` should be able to hold 1D array of `Ex1`

```
ex[0] = new Ex1[3];// but this can not be possible as Ex1[] IS A Object NOT Ex
```